# Change Xcode default debug scheme to a different one with cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

The iOS project that I lately started working on has multiple configurations - the default ones are `Debug` and `Release`. This one has some more (Staging, Beta, etc.).

When I run `pod install`, I see that cocoapods sets `Release`- type values for configurations other than `Debug` (`Build active architecture only`, `Optimization Level`, `Enable testability` and so on). So when I want to build and debug the App with the `Staging` configuration, it takes quite long because it's not properly configured for being debugged.

How can I tell cocoapods to set `Debug`-type values for my `Staging` configuration? I don't want to change those settings everytime manually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was happy to find the solution myself... sometimes it can be so easy...

```
project 'MyProject', 'Staging' => :debug
```